# 400x Appraisal Document Collaboration Spaces

Tags: collaboration

I hope someone can advise me how best to get started.

I need to create approximately 400 spaces where a single document can be collarborated on by 2 people, accessed by 5 in total.

There will be a need for them to view a folder containing a history of all of the previous collaborated documents but that they cannot tamper with. (theoretical structure in pic at the end).

Each of the 400 sets of 2 people need to organise a meeting, bounce a document back and forth, view the history meet and then handed over two the other 1-3 individuals once signed off.

I am reasonably new to SharePoint but have a history of eLearning development and have picked up the basics already.

I am asking this so that I don't get too far down a route when it might have been wise to take another one.

Before the current histories have been grouped into one document there are approximagelt 6000 files. I indend on Zipping the indivuiduals 'used' documents together as an archive as I hear there is an advised 10k file limit...

Is all this possible with SharePoint. Is there an easy way to import the shares structure to save doing each share individually? Or should I save my time and look for something elsewhere. Sharepoint is free for me to use in my org so if I can make this work then that would be great.?

Thanks in advance.

Matt

[image: Theoretical structure]

Comment: Would be able to run a powershell script in or add a custom solution to the farm? I mean, whats your level of access?

Comment: Not that level of access, but it could be run through the 'powers that be'. It might come out the other end. Question is what is the script for?

Comment: I asked because you can programmatically add all the files, create the libraries for the files and give specific permissions too.

Comment: I had guessed but just wanted to check.
It would be an option if I had that level of knowledge! :) Happy to learn though.